# QT C++ Чтение файла

Tags: c++, qt

Добрейшего времени суток.

Нужно передавать файлы посредствам TCP протокола. И у меня всё работает , за исключением ЧТЕНИЯ ДАННЫХ из оригинального файла. Дело в том, что

```
QFile file(pathToFile);
file.read(512);
```

такой код считывает корректно только символы с кодами ASCII от 0 до 128(из-за UTF-8).
Как собственно считывать так , чтобы каждый символ нормально считывался.
P.S. Видел как считывали с помощью

```
QString::fromAscii(file.read(512)).toBase64();
```

но похоже это устаревшая функция из старых версий QT.

Спасибо.

Comment: [`QString::fromUtf8`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#fromUtf8)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Из файла считывается поток байт, и QFile совершенно без разницы на кодировку.

```
QByteArray QIODevice::read(qint64 maxSize)
```

От вас требуется только правильно преобразовать байты в текст:

```
QByteArray data = file.readAll();
QString text;
// Если текст в локальной 8-бит кодировке (windows-1251);
text = QString::fromLocal8Bit(data); 
// Если текст в UTF-8
text = QString::fromUtf8(data);
```

и т.д. более подробно читайте документацию https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html

Если задача не вполне стандартная, можно воспользоваться QTextCodec для считывания других кодировок:

```
QTextCodec* codec = QTextCodec::codecForName("CP866"); // кодек для DOS кодировки
QTextStream s(&f);
s.setCodec(codec);
QString text = s.readAll();
```

Comment: Всё прикольно и круто , теперь передает специальные символы, но если считывать и передавать другие файлы , например картинку PNG , некоторые её символы гибнут и заменяются другими, не знаете в чем тут дело?

Comment: Не текстовые файлы не надо переводить в QString. Работайте с QByteArray